# SharePoint Alert Me not sending alerts for a specific user

Tags: wss-3.0, alert

We use the SharePoint alerting infrastructure on a list on a site. Alert are currently active for a group of users and are working correctly. The environment is SharePoint wss3.0.

I have added a new user to the alerting system.

The user got the email from SharePoint telling them that alerting had been setup from them.
(It was a simple, tell me everything, immediatly alert).

However whenever the list is modified (new items added, items modified, items deleted, anything) they do not recieve a notification while the other members also on "alert me" for this list do get the alert.

I don't understand why the user gets the notification telling them the alert is setup, but never gets an alert after that.

Any ideas would be greatly apprecitated!

Andy

Comment: Hi Andy, welcome to SharePoint Exchange. I have edited you question to fix the question title. Now your question should be clearer to people browsing the question list. Having a title that reflects the question will also help search, and improve your question visibility on the site.

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint Exchange. Can you advise if the site in question has been upgraded from WSS 2.0 or if it's native to WSS3.0? I've seen some upgrade instances where alerts had to be reconfigured after the migration. This may be applicable in your own environment if its an older site.

Comment: What's your farm configuration? Single server or multiple? Are all your users in the same AD/email domain? Are these all AD users or do you have FBA set up? Is your Exchange server local and in the same domain, and SharePoint is sending directly to it, or do you have SMTP running on one of the servers and are relaying to Exchange? Is there anything showing up in ULS when the notifications are sent? Is the server facing north? :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Active Directory users, make sure that the users who are not receiving alerts have their email specified in the Active Directory.

Comment: And no one fat fingered the email address.

Comment: off the topic but curious to know..what does "fat fingered" meaning

Comment: Fat fingered = bad typing.  You would type the incorrect email address.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I'll ask this question to check out the troubleshooting steps you've already performed.

Did you confirm that the message was not going to this specific users junk mail folder? OR, do they have a rule that sends alerts to another folder?

Did you try to add another user to the alert to see if they are receiving the messages as well?  Is it possible that the alert system is not saving new alerts?

I'd start there and see where things stand.

Good Luck!

Comment: The problem text says that other users are subscribed to the same change, and they're getting the alerts, so the alert system appears to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time these alerting issues have to do with permissions.

Check to see the difference between permissions of the users currently receiving alerts and the new user.

Also note that approval or publishing features may prevent some users from receiving "new item" alerts when they are not authorized to see drafts.

Comment: Whoops this is a very old question!